# Dispatching code depending on whether ggplot2 is installed

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-package

I'm working on an R package that I don't want to have any hard dependencies on other packages. One of the functions I'd like to include is a plotting function and `ggplot2` offers a lot of nice functionality, but I don't want to require users to install it if it isn't already installed. My thought was to create something like the below:

```r
package_quickplot <- function(given_data_frame){
  if("ggplot2"%in%.packages()){
    ggplot2::ggplot(given_data_frame) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(x=x_vals, y=y_vals))
  } else {
    with(given_data_frame, plot(x_vals, y_vals, type="l"))
  }
}
```

where the function checks if `ggplot2` is loaded, returning a ggplot if so or a base plot if not. This feels like a bad idea, but I can't articulate exactly why. I'd obviously include `ggplot2` in the Suggests header and it currently passes `devtools::check()` but I'm a little leery because I don't think I've seen this implemented elsewhere. The R Extensions manual describes the Suggests field as "includes packages used only in examples, tests or vignettes" which implies to me that this isn't what's intended. They describe in detail use cases for the `if(require("pkgname"))` for suggested code but specifically mention that require/library shouldn't be used in package code because it alters the search path.

Is it fine to dispatch code in this way?

Comment: I think you want `if("ggplot2" %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"]) print("yes")` instead of `if("ggplot2" %in% .packages()) print("yes")`.

Comment: @Friede I actually had that code before but decided that I only wanted to produce a ggplot if ggplot2 is already loaded, not just accessible. I thought that it would be confusing to suddenly throw up a ggplot if the user hasn't loaded it at all just because it's technically possible.

Comment: All you need to add then is `library(ggplot2)`. Assume someone uses your code at the top of an R script in a clean session. I see no use-case where `ggplot2`is already loaded.

Comment: `library(ggplot2)` creates a hard dependency for the package, which I'd like to avoid, and is generally a bad idea for packages

Comment: Absolutely. To be specific, I mean it in the sense of `ggplot2::ggplot(...) + ggplot2::gg_something()`

Comment: What about `if(require('ggplot2', quietly = TRUE)){ggplot(...)} else {plot(...)}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not standard to dispatch according to whether a package is *loaded*, which is what your code does. Typically, one would use `requireNamespace` to ensure that a package is *installed*. In fact, this is what `ggplot2` itself uses for suggested packages such as sf, hexbin ragg, and Hmisc. For example, [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4f05313b5e3cbfe71c2d3b9e9183780d66439843/R/save.R#L264). This is quicker than using `'ggplot2' %in% installed.packages()`

So your code might be better written as:

```r
package_quickplot <- function(given_data_frame) {

  if(requireNamespace("ggplot2", quietly = TRUE)) {
    ggplot2::ggplot(given_data_frame) +
      ggplot2::geom_line(ggplot2::aes(x = x_vals, y = y_vals))
  } else {
    with(given_data_frame, plot(x_vals, y_vals, type = "l"))
  }
}
```

Though I might separate the logic even more, and have your function dispatch an unexported ggplot-based plotting function or an unexported base R plotting function depending on `requireNamespace`.